# Java exception when running Change Assistant

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm trying to use Change Assistant to apply a patching from tools 8.51 to 8.51.19 (yes I know that's ancient).  I installed PeopleTools 8.51 and then installed PeopleTools 8.51.19 over the top of it.  Then I installed Change Assistant and configured it to Perform PeopleTools Only Upgrade in the Tools > Options menu.  Then I went to File > Import Template to import my upgrade template.  Then I went to File > New Environment and created my environment (the test connection succeeded).  But when I go to File > New Job and select my template and environment and Type of Upgrade = Initial Upgrade, I get this error

```
com.peoplesoft.pt.changeassistant.logging.Logger handleException 
WARNING: Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException caught 
in sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString() 
empty String java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Unknown Source) 
at com.peoplesoft.pt.changeassistant.Job.initStatus(Job.java:714) 
at com.peoplesoft.pt.changeassistant.Job. (Job.java:199) 
at com.peoplesoft.pt.changeassistant.client.main.frmMain$13.actionPerformed(frmMain.java:4261) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an older version of Change Assistant available to look at, but I think you want to actually "Apply a PeopleTools Patch" if going from 8.51.xx to 8.51.19.  I don't recall if that is called out separately in the older CA versions, but those are two different options in the latest versions and I think has been like that for a while.  The "Perform PeopleTools Only Upgrade", or "Upgrade PeopleTools", would usually mean going from something like 8.51 to 8.55.